# UIWebView is not responsive in iOS8 and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

The following code was working properly in iOS7, Now with iOS8 it is not getting and result. What could be the reason and the answer?

```
   NSURLRequest *url = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/1079798338712435"]]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:url];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not getting and result"?

Comment: Why are you initializing a file URL with an https:// value? File URLs are for references to local files. If this worked in previous versions of iOS, that was just good luck.

Comment: @FreeNickname I mean it is giving a white webView without any output.

Comment: @JawadSabir if my answer helps you. you can mark it as a accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it using html request instead of URL, I believe it is iOS8 bug. here is how I got the results

```
  NSString*url2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com"];

    NSURL*url3 = [NSURL URLWithString:url2];

    NSString*htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code and do proper connection:

```
NSString *stream=@"http://youtube.com";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:stream];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 2):

You got a mistake: do not use `-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]` with http link

I'm sure that `url` is nil when running your code, and your webview loaded a NIL url, so there is nothing happened

Use `-[NSURL initWithString:]` instead

Good luck